# Binding and search to OpenLDAP returns "no such object" when trying to ldapsearch attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have recently updated my debian to jessie. After the upgrade - including slapd - I can bind to the ldap server but cannot read or change attributes. For example

```
ldapsearch -LLL -W -x -h edhu -D "uid=mrx,ou=People,dc=example,dc=local" -b "ou=People,dc=example,dc=local" shadowLastChange
```

returns `No such object (32)`

Password is fine and the binding works but I cannot read any object attributes. Here is my ACL

```
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local" write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to dn.one=ou=People,dc=example,dc=local by self write
olcAccess: {3}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree=dc=example,dc=local by dn="cn=reader,dc=example,dc=local" read
```

OpenLDAP 2.4.40

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seemed to be a problem with a second ldap database where a checksum error appeared. After correcting that checksum error all ist fine again :-)